# How can I make this method return an array?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading

How can I make the following method return a `character array` ?

```
public char[] startThread() {
    // arr declaration
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            arr = getArray(); // arr assignment
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
    return arr;
}

char arrNew[] = startThread();
```

*Note :  The above snippet generates an error*

Answer (score 3):

Look for java.util.concurrent.Callable, its similar to runnable but returns a value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

or

If in 1.6 JDK, you can look for Future objects.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.

When you return from your method, you don't have your char array. It is not created yet. So, assigning *as a reference* will not work. Neither `Callable` will help on this.

What you can do is that you create a holder object, and return that (this is very similar to `Future` objects):

```
public static class ArrayHolder {
    public char[] arr;
}

public ArrayHolder startThread() {

    final ArrayHolder holder = new ArrayHolder();

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            holder.arr = getArray(); // arr assignment
        }
    };
    new Thread(r).start();
    return holder;
}

ArrayHolder h = startThread();
char arrNew[] = h.arr;
```

Notice, that `h.arr` will change in time, so the first time you call it it will most likely return `null`

Comment: I cannot assign to a final variable. Do you see the function call ?

Comment: You may not assign a new value to arr from inside the Runnable, so this example wont work.

Comment: @GyroGearless you're right, I tried it, reconstructing my example.